# Not executing setInterval every time

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval

I am making a stopwatch.
I want to display the interval between the time the start button is pressed and now in a p tag at any moment.
I tried this:

```js
watch() {
      const p = document.createElement("p");
      p.id = "p";
      document.body.appendChild(p);
      document.getElementById("p")!.innerHTML = this.stop();
   }
   start() {
      if(this.status === 'started') throw new Error('already started');
      this.currentTime = Date.now();
      this.interVal = setInterval(() => this.watch(), 100);
      this.status = 'started';
      return this.interVal;
   }
   stop() {
      if(this.status === 'stopped') throw new Error('already stopped');
      this.duration = Date.now() - this.currentTime + this.duration;
      console.log(this.duration);
      this.status = 'stopped';
      return this.duration;
   }
```

Comment: Tell me if you need more code

Comment: You haven't exactly explained what your issue is

Comment: setInterval inside the start function is executed only once. I want to have the distance every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `setInterval()` is repeatedly calling the `this.watch()` method, which subsequently calls the `this.stop()` method each time.

In the `this.stop()` method, you always set `this.status = 'stopped'` before returning. However, at the beginning of the method, you also check that if the status is equal to `'stopped'`, then you throw an `Error`. As a result, `this.stop()` can only be called once, because the first invocation sets `this.status` to `'stopped'`, which causes an `Error` to be thrown on every following invocation. And since `this.watch()` doesn't "catch" any thrown errors, the error will continue to bubble up, and `this.watch()` never finishes executing, therefore never updating the innerHTML.

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, but to prevent the error from occurring, remove the line `if(this.status === 'stopped') throw new Error('already stopped');` from `this.stop()`.